# How to animate a div with a position fixed in react js?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a header component which gets the fixed class after user scrolls down a bit like this :

```
 const [show, setShow] = React.useState(false);

  const handleShow = () => {
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      if (window.pageYOffset > 120) {
        if (!show) {
          console.log("set to true");
          setShow(true);
        }
      }
      if (window.pageYOffset < 120) {
        console.log("set to false");
        setShow(false);
      }
    }
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      window.addEventListener("scroll", handleShow);
    }
    return () => {
      if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
        window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleShow);
      }
    };
  }, []);

return (
       <div
          className={show ? classes.fixed : ""}
          style={{
            background: bgColor,
            boxShadow: "0 0 10px #ccc",
          }}
        >
          <div className="d-flex justify-content-center">
           <div>Header</div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

And the css code for fixed class is :

```
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 100%;
}
```

It gets fixed to the top but the transition doesn't work and I want the header to get fixed at the top with some kind of animation .

How can I animate with position fixed for a div ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue with applying to classes to the div :

```
 <div
          className={
            show ? `${classes.navbar} ${classes.navbarSticky}` : classes.navbar
          }
          style={{
            background: bgColor,
            boxShadow: "0 0 10px #ccc",
          }}
        >
          <div className="d-flex justify-content-between p-4">
            <div>{left}</div>
            <div>{right}</div>
          </div>
          {bottom}
        </div>
```

and the styles are :

```
.navbar {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}

.navbarSticky {
  background: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  animation: moveDown 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes moveDown {
  from {
    transform: translateY(-5rem);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(0rem);
  }
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(0rem);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add lazy moving animation. Instead of using `position: fixed;` use position: absolute and on every scroll end of window capture the scroll delta and set it on div. Pseudocode is as follow:

- Append scroll event
- On every scroll end capture the Y scroll position.
- Now set that captured Y scroll position on that div (header) who have `position: absolute;`

If this sounds confusing to you then let me know then I can share the code as well.

Hopes this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and yes please share your code thanks again .